# How to handle "get" on a procedure in PostScript

Tags: syntax, postscript

I'm writing a postscript interpreter but don't know how the following code should be handled. Specifically, I don't know how to handle using `get` on a Procedure (the last line of the code block). Is `get` valid for procedures? If so, are the nested procedures treated as one element? If so, does that mean `{ pop 0 }` should be added to the stack?

```
userdict /internaldict 
{
  count 0 eq 
  { /internaldict errordict /invalidaccess get exec }
  if

  dup type /integertype ne 
  { /internaldict errordict /invalidaccess get exec }
  if 

  dup 1183615869 eq 
  { pop 0 }
  { /internaldict errordict /invalidaccess get exec }
  ifelse 
}
dup 14 get 1 25 dict put
```

Thanks for any clarification you can provide!

Comment: Good luck with your interpreter! You may find useful information in the answers to [juFo's Postscript questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:187650%20[postscript]%20is:question) (many by me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, fundamentally, read Section 3.3.6 of the 3rd edition PostScript Language Reference Manual, where this is (as usual) quite clearly explained.

> A packed array is a more compact representation of an ordinary array,
>   intended primarily for use as a procedure. A packed array object is
>   distinct from an ordinary array object (it has type packedarray
>   instead of array), but in most respects it behaves the same as an
>   ordinary array.

As the text goes on to say, packedarrays are mostly indistinguishable from regular arrays, so `get` functions on the packed array exactly as on a normal array.

So to take a concrete example:

```
%% procedure to convert PostScript units to inches
%% usage: units inch inches

/inch {
 72 div
} bind def
```

Now if I do:

```
/inch load 0 get ==
```

The result is 72, while

```
/inch load 1 get ==
```

results in

--div--

In the case of the code you posted, the 'get' will retrieve the 14th element (starting from 0) of the packed array. In your case that will be:

```
{pop 0}
```

All the usual rules for arrays apply, so arrays inside arrays are a single element of the parent.

Because the 0th element is `count`, the 1st element is `0`, the second is `eq`, the third is another packedarray `{ /internaldict errordict /invalidaccess get exec }` etc etc.

So yes, you should end up with {pop 0} on the operand stack.

You do know that you can use Ghostscript to investigate this kind of problem yourself ? If for some reason you don't believe that Ghostscript is a conforming PostScript interpreter you can always check its behaviour with the PLRM.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the matter! I didn't know that Ghostscript could be used in such a way, I'll be sure to check it out in future!

Comment: I think these are probably just executable arrays, but not packed. Otherwise the `put` will cause a problem.